# Why "t" letter is written in small while writing 'Hashtable' syntax name?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, hashtable

Why "t" letter is written in small while writing 'Hashtable' syntax name.
why "t" is not a capital tetter like "M" in HashMap & "S" in HashSet?

Comment: I doubt anybody, other than the original designers of the API could seriously answer that questions.  May be the developer whose task it was to write `Hashtable` had a broken `t` key...?

Comment: Hashtable and Vector predate the standardized Collections API. And, because it is.

Answer (score 3):

`HashMap`, `TreeMap` are implementation of `Map` interface, so Hash-Map and Tree-Map as `HashSet` & `TreeSet` are implemenataion of `Set` interface.

But `Hashtable` is not implementation of `Table`. `Hashtable` is in java since jdk1.0 and it was -

```
public class Hashtable extends Dictionary implements Cloneable, Serializable{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how class name define in `Hashtable` in `Java`

```
public class Hashtable<K,V>
extends Dictionary<K,V>
implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable {}
```

This is not really a question I think, By design they name their class as `Hashtable`.

This may did intentionally, since `Map` and `Set` are interfaces. `Table` is not.

`Map` is a interface while `HashMap` is a implementation of it.

`Set` is a interface while `TreeSet` is a implementation of it.

But

There is not interface call `Table` only a class `Hashtable`

Comment: `Hashtable` is wrongly spelt twice (as `Hashtabel`)

Answer (score 1):

> Since Map and Set are interfaces and hence HashMap and HashSet have capitals... and there is no such collection interface named Table as such..

[Full conversation](http://www.coderanch.com/t/552595/java/java/small-Hashtable-class-java)